# start() method in applet removes panel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, applet, event-dispatch-thread

I made an applet.  I used `JPanel` to set content of the applet, I do in the `init()` method and in `start()` I do other stuff.  When I ran the applet without including the `start()` everything is okay and the content appears, but if I added the `start()` method the applet doesn't show the contents.

Why is that?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Server extends JApplet {

final static int port = 4444;
ServerSocket listen;
JEditorPane message;
JPanel content;

    public void init(){
        message = new JEditorPane();
        message.setText("Listening...");
        message.setEditable(false);
        message.setVisible(true);

        content = new JPanel();
        content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        content.add(message, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        setContentPane(content);
    }

    public void start(){    
         try {
             listen = new ServerSocket(port);
             while(true){   
                Socket client = listen.accept();    
                HandleConnection hc= new HandleConnection(client);
            }

            } catch (IOException e) {
              System.out.println("Couldn't listen on port "+port);
        }
        }

    public void stop(){}
    public void destroy(){}
}
```

Comment: Do you see any exceptions in the applet console?

Comment: Please ***read*** the text relating to the tags that are slapped on a question!  The description of the [tag:start] tag explicitly states that it is not to be used.

Answer (score 5):

You're stomping on the Swing event thread with your `while (true)` block. Because this thread, also known as the Event Dispatch Thread, or EDT, is responsible for all of your GUI's graphics and user interactions, running a long-running bit of code on it will effectively freeze your GUI completely. Solution: Don't do this on the event thread, but instead do this in a background thread such as that provided by a SwingWorker object. For more on this, please read [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: Besides that excellent advice.  Refactor accepting connections into a method, declare an attribute called `acceptConnections` and change the opening line to `while(acceptConnections)..`.  Set the flag `true` and call it from `start()`.  Set the flag false on `stop()`.  I shudder every time I see `while(true)` - it has a bad code smell.

Comment: so i made another Thread which runs the server listener and its working , thx for the info :)